# imputing forward / backward

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to impute some longitudinal data in this way (see below). For each individual (id), if first values are NA, I would like to impute using the first observed value for that individual regardless when that occurs. Then, I would like to impute forward based on the last value observed for each individual (see imputed below).

var values might not necessarily increase monotonically. Those values might be a character vector.

I have tried several ways to do this, but still I cannot get a satisfactory solution.

Any ideas?

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,7,9)
var <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2,3,NA)
imputed <- c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,3)
dat <- data.table(id, time, var, imputed)

   id time var imputed
 1:  1    1  NA       1
 2:  1    2  NA       1
 3:  1    3   1       1
 4:  1    4  NA       1
 5:  1    5   2       2
 6:  1    6   3       3
 7:  1    7  NA       3
 8:  2    3  NA       2
 9:  2    5   2       2
10:  2    7   3       3
11:  2    9  NA       3
```

Comment: do you want to have 1 in imputed column when NA exist ? this is what you want ? please try to give an example data and an expected output

Comment: @Nemo "var" is the original variable, "imputed" is what I want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(zoo)

dat[, newimp := na.locf(na.locf(var, FALSE), fromLast=TRUE), by = id]
dat
#    id time var imputed newimp
# 1:  1    1  NA       1      1
# 2:  1    2  NA       1      1
# 3:  1    3   1       1      1
# 4:  1    4  NA       1      1
# 5:  1    5   2       2      2
# 6:  1    6   3       3      3
# 7:  1    7  NA       3      3
# 8:  2    3  NA       2      2
# 9:  2    5   2       2      2
#10:  2    7   3       3      3
#11:  2    9  NA       3      3
```